# Why I can't use Cloud9 IDE on WP 8.1?

Tags: cloud9-ide

when i'm trying to login to Cloud 9 IDE on smartphone I get only "Dashboard loading" message. Why? What difference is between mobile and desktop browsers in this case? Mobile devices are fast anougth today and have gigabites of RAM and big High-res screens. Same browser engines.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices typically require touch support and responsive layout, which can be more difficult when it comes to an IDE. Keyboard support can be another challenge.